# Unsupported command format with token - '""' Aerospike

Tags: aerospike, aql

I am trying to insert a record in aerospike as following :

```
insert into NameSpace.SetName(PK,id,value,formId) values("1","23","hello","");
```

**And I am getting following error:**

```
Unsupported command format with token -  '""' 
Make sure string values are enclosed in quotes.
Type " aql --help " from console or simply "help" from within the aql- 
prompt.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the explicit value of the bin formId supposed to be?

Comment: it can be anything alphanumeric but empty string i want to put default value

Comment: Which version of AQL are you using, and which version of the server?

Comment: Currently I am using 3.14 version and its in production we can't update as of now , Any work around ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to work for me:

```
$ aql
Seed:         127.0.0.1
User:         None
Aerospike Query Client
Version 3.15.3.14
C Client Version 4.3.12
Copyright 2012-2017 Aerospike. All rights reserved.
aql> insert into test.stackoverflow (PK,id,value,formId) values("1","23","hello","");
OK, 1 record affected.

aql> select * from test.stackoverflow where PK="1"
+------+---------+--------+
| id   | value   | formId |
+------+---------+--------+
| "23" | "hello" | ""     |
+------+---------+--------+
1 row in set (0.011 secs)

OK
```

The server version is

```
$ asd --version
Aerospike Community Edition build 4.3.0.2
```

Alternatively, use one of the language clients. You shouldn't be trying to build an application over AQL, it's just a tool for admin (with light-weight data browsing).

**Install**

```
$ sudo yum install python-devel
$ sudo yum install openssl-devel
$ pip install aerospike
$ python
```

**Run**

```
>>> import aerospike
>>> config = {'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 3000)]}
>>> client = aerospike.client(config).connect()
>>> key = ('test', 'stackoverflow', '1')
>>> client.put(key, {'id': '23', 'value': 'hello', 'formId': ''})
0L
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(client.get(key))
(('test',
  'stackoverflow',
  None,
  bytearray(b'CHu\xf09%a\xf0\x8d\x86\x14\x0f\xea\x93\xeb\xf6\x7f\x16\x87\xd0')),
 {'gen': 1, 'ttl': 431818},
 {'formId': '', 'id': '23', 'value': 'hello'})
```

Comment: Currently I am using 3.14 version and its in production we can't update as of now , Any work around ??

Comment: Why do it though? You can always add the formID bin to the record when you have real data to put in.

Comment: (1) You can install the [tools package](https://www.aerospike.com/download/tools/latest) on another machine (not a cluster node) and talk to the cluster with it. (2) A work around would be to use the [Python](https://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/python/) command line, or script it in any language. AQL is just a tool built on top of the C client. The same functionality exists in the [clients](https://www.aerospike.com/download/client/) for Java, C#, Python, Go, Node.js, ...